# I can't seem to find a way to make my discord bot send a message after being invited to a server

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So, when I was making my bot project, I wanted to add a feature in which sends a message after being invited to a server, as a way of thanking the owner for the invitation, however, I cannot seem to find a way to get this since most of the solutions are outdated, due to the version of the library. Any suggestions?

**User Invites the bot**

**Bot:** "Thanks for inviting me blah blah blah"

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: Would you be able to share some of your code or what you have tried already?

Comment: I have used one similar to the one in the answer, but it does not work as it states `chnl.send("testing")` is not a function, while it clearly is defined, here's the code:

`client.on('guildCreate', guild => { 
    let chnl = guild.channels.cache.first();
    if(chnl) return chnl.send('test');
 console.log(chnl)
});
`

Comment: @Syntle I'm using the most recent one, Discord.js v12.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the guildCreate event, that gets triggered every time the bot joins a server, example:

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => { 
    let channel = guild.channels.cache.first();
    if(channel) channel.send('Hey!');
}
```

In this example we get a random channel from the guild and send a message in it, you might also check if the bot has the permission to send messages.

Comment: @Syntle we do not get the "first" channel in the server, because with the first() method you get the channel with the smaller ID in the cache, so it's still random most of the time